# AngularJS - Repeating a div and a button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat to repeat a div. This div also has a button within it.

Currently, I'm doing it by creating the div and the button in the javascript part and pushing the final result in an array :

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
var newButton = document.createElement('button');
newDiv.appendChild(newButton);
$scope.arrayDiv.push(newDiv);
```

I have 2 questions :

**1) What should be the html syntax ? Is the following correct ?**

```
<div id='main_chart_div' ng-repeat="x in arrayDiv" value={{x}}></div>
```

**2) Is there a way to do that without manipulating the DOM ?**

Comment: Why are you creating this in the javascript?

Comment: I'm using GoogleChart, and I need the id of the div to affect a chart. So the easiest solution (for me at least!) was to do this in javascript. But i'm trying to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the button in your template:

```
<div id='main_chart_div' ng-repeat="x in arrayDiv" value={{x}}>
 <button></button>
</div>
```

By the way, you shouldn't repeat an element with a static `id`.

Comment: Ugh, I guess I didn't understood how ng-repeat actually works. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @olivierGrech `arrayDiv` should be an actual array contaning information you want to render in your div...

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `ng-bind-html` within `ng-repeat`.

> ng-bind-html evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way.

Secure way is with either `ngSanitize` or make use of `$sce`. [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Zd4Li0oo151eFVN4SP6?p=preview)

Filter directive for safe binding:

```
app.filter('safeHtml', function ($sce) {
   return function (val) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});
```

View :

```
<div id='main_chart_div' ng-repeat="x in arrayDiv">
    <p ng-bind-html="x.html | safeHtml"></p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.arrayDiv = [{html: '<h1>Heading</h1>'}];

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
var newButton = document.createElement('button');
newButton.innerHTML = "Button";
newDiv.appendChild(newButton);

$scope.arrayDiv.push({html : newDiv.outerHTML});
```